# += must be l-value in Visual C

Tags: c, operators, comparison-operators

Can someone explain to me why

```
iterator += 1;
```

Works but

```
(isexpression < toexpression) ? iterator += byexpression : iterator -= byexpression;
```

Doesn't in ANSI C, being written and compiled in visual studio?

I get the following error: error C2106: '+=' : left operand must be l-value

Thanks,

Danny

Comment: In C, a conditional expression doesn't yield an lvalue, hence `( (isexpression < toexpression) ? iterator += byexpression : iterator ) -= byexpression;` is illegal. And the right side of the colon may not be an assignment-expression, so `(isexpression < toexpression) ? (iterator += byexpression) : (iterator -= byexpression);` is illegal as well if you remove the parantheses. If you add the parantheses, it should be legal (because `(iterator += byexpression)` is a primary-expression).

Comment: This isn't an answer to your question, but I think an `if`/`else` would be much more clear here, i.e.
`if (isexpression < toexpression)
    iterator += byexpression;
else
    iterator -= byexpression;`  If you feel you must use the ternary operator, how about `iterator += (isexpression < toexpression) ? byexpression : -byexpression;`.

Answer (score 5):

This is because the compiler interprets

```
(isexpression < toexpression) ? iterator += byexpression : iterator -= byexpression;
```

as

```
((isexpression < toexpression) ? iterator += byexpression : iterator) -= byexpression;
```

because of the [operator precedence](http://www.difranco.net/compsci/C_Operator_Precedence_Table.htm) of  ternary conditional operator  `?:` is higher than that of `-=` or `+=`. Because of this the sub-expression `iterator` get bound to `?:` instead of `-=`. Left hand side of `-=` operator must be an l-value but `?:` operator never produce an l-value, that's why you are getting the error

```
error C2106: '+=' : left operand must be l-value
```

Always remember parentheses are your friend. You can remove this error by parenthesizing it as

```
(isexpression < toexpression) ? (iterator += byexpression) : (iterator -= byexpression);
```

Comment: Thanks, adding in some () did the job! Didn't realize ? was higher than -= and +=!

Comment: "Precedence" is a bit misleading here: `(isexpression < toexpression) ? iterator += byexpression : (iterator -= byexpression);` is perfectly fine; i.e. you only need the parentheses for the expression *after* the colon. Adding parentheses to the expression between `?` and `:` doesn't hurt, though, and probably improves readability here.

Comment: @DanTonyBrown: It is not "higher". The `?:` is an example of operator whose "precedence" cannot be expressed in linear terms. Strictly speaking, the language has no well-defined notion of "precedence". It is a simplification that works "almost always". This happens to be a situation where it doesn't work.

Comment: @AndreyT; But I read that `?:` has higher precedence than that of `=, +=, -=, *=,, /=, %=`. Is that wrong?